# How to simplify boolean expressions.

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm struggling to understand what rules to apply when simplifying boolean expression.

For example:

> $$ B+(A\cdot(C+B) \overline C) $$

I'm not sure how to simplify this expression. Here is my attempt.

$$
= B+AB\cdot(C+\overline C)
\\
= B+AB\cdot(1)
\\
= B(A+B)
\\
= B(B+A)
\\
= B
$$

Comment: What are your definitions? Is "middle dot" and "concatenation" different?

Comment: @BenjaminWang My bad. A "dot" represents an AND i.e multiplication and "+" represents an OR, i.e addition

Comment: Okay so what does B(A+B) mean? You put B next to A+B. Is this also multiplying?

Comment: @BenjaminWang B AND (A OR B)

Comment: Can you explain how you got the first line of your attempt?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this almost the same way you'd simplify an ordinary algebra expression:

$B+(A\cdot(C+B) \overline C)$

So just simplify it like an ordinary algebra expression first (technically we're using that AND is distributive over OR... in the same way multiplication is distributive over addition in ordinary algebra)

$=B+A(C\overline C+B\overline C)$. So here I'm just using $(C+B)\overline C = C\overline C + B\overline C$

Now I can use $C \overline C = 0$

$=B+A(0+B\overline C)$

$=B+A(B\overline C)$

$=B+B(A\overline C)$ (using commutativity and associativity of AND... just like in ordinary multiplication)

$=B(1+A\overline C)$ (factoring)

In boolean algebra 1+ anything is just 1.

$=B(1)$

$=B$

There are other tricks... but the initial main "tactic" is just to treat AND like multiplication and OR like addition.

Comment: Nice answer @Ameet Sharma :D

Answer (score 1):

Two really useful principles are:

**Absorption**

$P + PQ = P$

**Reduction**

$P+ P'Q = P + Q$

With these:

$ B+A(C+B)C' \overset{Reduction}{=}$

$B+ ABC' \overset{Absorption}{=}$

$B$

Done!